# UKFTractogtaphy fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: linux, git, github

when I performed the UKFTractography code from github.I use the command "make",then I met the problem like:
[  1%] Generating UKF_GIT_HASH
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
make[2]: *** [ukf/CMakeFiles/_GEN_GITVER.dir/build.make:60: ukf/CMakeFiles/_GEN_GITVER] Error 128
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1043: ukf/CMakeFiles/_GEN_GITVER.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
how could I solve it?

I used the correct coommand from author and  tried different OS CentOS and Ubuntu.I met the same question.

Comment: You need to add steps (commands) to reproduce. Like the `git clone` command.

Comment: How could I realize it,modify the makefile?

Comment: You didn’t clone the repository? The error says that you need to be inside of a Git repository. If you clone the repository, then go into the resulting directory, then you will be inside a Git repo. So if you clone the repo from GitHub you should be fine.